# Confusion about Layout Managers to use

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

I am creating a simple game using Java. I have created the game's menu using JFrame. I am having confusion about what layouts to be used to place the Menu Buttons(Start,High Scores,Instructions,Exit) at the center. I have an approach in mind that is :
Creating a grid layout of three columns and in the middle column adding a box layout(having the menu buttons) positioned at the center of this column.

Should I use this approach? if not then please tell me the solution.

Comment: Maybe you should try it and see, then ask here if you have a specific problem?

Comment: Use a `GridBagLayout`, you may want to check out [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

[image]

```
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
JButton scoreButton = new JButton("High Score");
JButton instructButton = new JButton("Instructions");
JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = java.awt.gbc.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
getContentPane().add(startButton, gbc);

gbc.gridy = 1;
getContentPane().add(scoreButton, gbc);

gbc.gridy = 2;
getContentPane().add(instructButton, gbc);

gbc.gridy = 3;
getContentPane().add(exitButton, gbc);
```

Comment: thanks it really worked, but i having some confusions in understanding some terms related to these layouts. But MADProgrammer i think instead of  gbc.insets = java.awt.gbc.HORIZONTAL, it should be gbc.insets = GridBagLaoutConstraints.HORIZONTAL 

again, thanks for the help

Comment: madprogrammer! your look and feel of buttons is different than mine. rectanglular shaped buttons are showing, but what i have to do to have the above look-and-feel.

Comment: I use the default system look & feel (in this case Windows), ie UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())

Answer (score 0):

Madprogrammer is right, use a gridbaglayout. I myself am actually too lazy to fool around with layout managers so I use WindowBuilder for Eclipse SDK. Search for it on google. WindowBuilder has bi directional code generation (ie, it can parse swing code and then generate it from what you do in the gui), and its all drag and drop.